# Django Request Object in middleware?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, prometheus

I'm constructing a custom Prometheus middleware class to do some monitoring and I'd like to either construct or retrieve the Django Rest Framework `Request` object for a given request in middleware so that I can capture `request.version` in my metrics.

However, the `request` parameter in my code below appears to be a `WSGIRequest` object. Is it possible to discern the DRF `HttpRequest` object within middleware? Code Below...

```
if django.VERSION >= (1, 10, 0):
   from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
else:
   MiddlewareMixin = object

class CustomPrometheusAfterMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

   def process_response(self, request, response):
       # Do some cool things
       return response
```

Comment: @Alasdair I was first going to post the same comment but what the OP want is DRF's `Request` object.

Comment: What is the order of your middleware classes? can you post that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [check the source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L472), the Django's `HttpRequest` object is wrapped in DRF's `Request` object in `views.APIView.dispatch` so I think you will have to go thru quite a few hoops to get it. Your best bet might be to patch `APIView` to store the infos you're after on the real request (Django's `HttpRequest` or subclass of) - or on the response FWIW - so you can get them back in the middleware.